# If one job failed in bamboo it does not fail the build

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, bamboo, bitbucket-server, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I tried to execute two Power-shell script. 1st one is incorrect and 2nd one is correct but bamboo shows Successful build.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends why the first script is "incorrect". If it is throwing an error code, by default it will still return a success, as the script successfully ran, even if the results were an error. You might want to look into using `$LastExitCode` after you call the Powershell script to get the status of the script itself.